# What is the probability of flopping 2 pair with paired hole cards in Holdem?

Tags: probability, poker

I was looking into it and the only thing that I'm not sure is whether in the equation for this probability has to be multiplied by 3 or 2.

48/50 x 3/49 x 44/48 x2 =10.78%

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Could you explain how this game works?

Comment: Its texas holdem poker.